# Rail 4 Devise nil current_user for POST, PUT, DELETE JSON requests

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mongoid

Below is the code for ApplicationController and OrdersController.

While POST request to create new order, I get current_user nil in login_required and get Filter Chain halted.

```
********** Request Format: [application/json] - current_user:[] - user_signed_in: [false]
14:30:26 web.1  | Filter chain halted as :login_required rendered or redirected
14:30:26 web.1  | Completed 401 Unauthorized in 19ms (Views: 0.3ms)
```

Using devise database_authentication. Do not want to use token_authentication.
Advise needed how to get the current_user for POST/PUT JSON requests.

- Ruby: 2.1.1
- Rails: 4
- Devise: 3.2.4
- warden: 1.2.3

*ApplicationController:*

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery 
  # with: :null_session

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def login_required
    logger.info("********** Request Format: [#{request.format}] - current_user:[#{current_user}] - user_signed_in: [#{user_signed_in?}]")
    if request.format == :html
      authenticate_user!
      return
    end

    unless current_user
      is_validated = false
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => is_validated,
           :status => :unauthorized}
        format.protobuf { render :text => ProtoHelper.to_session_proto(is_validated),
           :status => :unauthorized}
      end
    end
  end
end

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required

  # POST /orders.json
  # POST /orders.protobuf
  def create
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue was with devise clearing `session[_csrf_token]` after user sign in. This made rails `protect_from_forgery` call to throw warning message: "Can't verify CSRF token" in logs and fails to find user in session.

Solution:

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

set the config variable: `clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication` to **false**, by default devise has this setting true.

```
config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = false
```